# eclipse Web Page Editor: div's not in line

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm working in eclipse with the Web Tools Platform, which provides a WYIWYG-feature. Now I got the problem, that two -containers are not shown in the same line. The really weird thing is, that when I export the file to desktop and open it with my browser, de two containers are shown in line, but there are no margins. Why are there two different looks? I mean, it is possible that the eclipse plug-in doesn't work well, but at the latest when I open the file in browser, it should display what I code or not?

Here are two pictures of what I want to explain:

[image]

[image]

here is the html-file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainStyle2.css" />
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header"><b>main title</b></div>

        <div id="navigation" style="float:left">
            <b>Navigation</b> <br /><hr />
            Welcome<br />
            Team<br />
            Links<br />
            Screenshots<br />
        </div>
        <div id="contCont" style="float:left">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

... and the css-file:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

#container{         background-color:#00FF59;
                    width:1200px;}

#header{            background-color:#99FF99;
                    text-align:center;
                    font-family:bookman old style;
                    font-size:50px;
                    margin-top:20; margin-bottom:10;
                    margin-left:20; margin-right:20;}

#navigation{        background-color:#99FF99;
                    width:200px; height: 800px;
                    font-family:bookman old style;
                    font-size:20;
                    margin-top:10; margin-bottom:10;
                    margin-left:20; margin-right:20;}

#contCont{          background-color:#99FF99;
                    width:1000px; height: 800px;
                    font-family:bookman old style;}
```

NOTE: I already tested it with `float:left` in both "navigation" and "contCont", but there was no changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WYSIWYG that IDEs provide are generally not very trustable.

Either way, try this:

```
#navigation{        background-color:#99FF99;
                width:200px; height: 800px;

                font-family:bookman old style;
                font-size:20px;
                margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; float: left;
                margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;}

#contCont{          background-color:#99FF99;
                width:960px; height: 800px; float:right;
                font-family:bookman old style;}
```

Also wrap the navigation and contCont in another div.

Another thing to note is that browsers have default styles for html tags. You should be resetting them for example:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Another thing that I noticed that for your margins, you are not specifying any units? Fixed it on the original code at the top. That's why the margins wont display in a real browser.

Also as previously mentioned, your container is too small because you are not taking in the margins.

Answer (score 1):

try adding some margins to #contCont, it would also help to create a jsfiddle for trial and error purposes, generally wysiwyg is not the best idea for development.
you should also be adding your margins to the overall width of the container so if you have nav with width of 200px and 20px margins on each side, and the content div is 1000px, your container should be 1240px wide